# How do math programs solve calculus-based problems?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

There are many mathematical programs out there out of which some are able to solve calculus-based problems, **GeoGebra**, **Qalculate!** to name a few.

How are those programs able to solve calculus-based problems which humans need to evaluate using a long procedure?
For example, the problem:
[image: integral problem]
It takes a lot of steps for humans to solve this problem as shown here on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-integrate-log-cos-x-from-0-to-pi-2).
How can those mathematical programs solve them with such a good accuracy?
[image]

Comment: [Computer algebra systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) solve equations the same way humans do, just faster. It's not clear from the example whether the program you're using actually finds the antiderivative of f and evaluates it, or merely calculates a [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) to approximate the result to some known precision, but either way, the computer isn't doing anything different from what a human mathematician could do with pencil, paper and a lot of free time.

Comment: Thanks for the links. The Riemann sum might be helpful for me. But, why did my question got a downvote? Is this question not suitable for SO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Church-Turing thesis implies that anything a human being can calculate can be calculated by any Turing-equivalent system of computation - including programs running on computers. That is to say, if we can solve the problem (or calculate an approximate answer that meets some criteria) then a computer program can be made to do the same thing. Let's consider a simpler example:

```
f(x) = x
a = Integral(f, 0, 1)
```

A human being presented with this problem has two options:

1. try to compute the antiderivative using some procedure, then use procedures to evaluate the definite integral over the supplied range
2. use some numerical method to calculate an approximate value for the definite integral which meets some criteria for closeness to the true value

In either case, human beings have a set of tools that allow them to do this:

1. recognize that f(x) is a polynomial in x. There are rules for constructing the antiderivatives of polynomials. Specifically, each term ax^b in the polynomial can be converted to a/(b+1)x^(b+1) and then an arbitrary constant c added to the end. We then say Sf(x)dx = (1/2)x^2 + c. Now that we have the antiderivative, we have a procedure for computing the antiderivative over a range: calculate Sf(x)dx for the high value, then subtract from that the result of calculating Sf(x)dx for the low value. This gives ((1/2)1^2) - ((1/2)0^2) = 1/2 - 0 = 1/2.
2. decide that for our purposes a Riemann sum with dx=1/10 is sufficient and that we'll take the midpoint value. We get 10 rectangles with base 1/10 and heights 1/20, 3/20, 5/20, 7/20, 9/20, 11/20, 13/20, 15/20, 17/20 and 19/20, respectively. The areas are 1/200, 3/200, 5/200, 7/200, 9/200, 11/200, 13/200, 15/200, 17/200 and 19/200. The sum of these is (1+3+5+7+9+11+13+15+17+19)/200 = 100/200 = 1/2. We happened to get the exact answer since we used the midpoint value and evaluated the definite integral of a linear function; in general, we'd have been close but not exact.

The only difficulty is in adequately specifying the procedure human beings use to solve these problems in various ways. Once specified, computers are perfectly capable of doing them. And make no mistake, human beings have a procedure - conscious or subconscious - for doing these problems reliably.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer and examples. I am sure that is the case because the mathematical program I use cannot solve the complex integrations if limits are not given.

Comment: @Puspam In practice, computing the definite integral of many (most?) interesting functions is not analytically tractable, so numerical methods are used to get approximations. There is a whole field, numerical analysis, which studies numerical methods to solve various problems and those methods' properties (runtime, precision, accuracy, etc.) Very deep subject.